# Trying to solve this for couple of days but Can seem to understand the right formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I been trying to figure out this formula but can seem to write it up.

I got 4 variables

a = 100;
b = 225;
c = 500;
D = is the sum of all 825;

if I reduce D from 825 to 600 and leave B the value it is ,
How much should A and C be? 
They have to be the same proportion.

So the idea is inside 825cm box I got 3 boxes ( 100, 225, 500)
I reduce 825 to 600 and when I reduce B does not get reduce but the rest do.
What is the formula for A and C to be reduced proportionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.
The old variables: $a = 100$; $b = 225$; $c = 500$; $d =a+b+c=825$.

The new variables: $A = ?$; $B = 225$; $C = ?$; $D =A+B+C=600$.

The new varibales $A$ and $C$ are in the same proportion of the older varibles $a$ and $c$ means that their ratios are the same, that is $A/C=a/c$.

Notice that 
$$A+C=D-B=600-225=375\quad\mbox{and}\quad A/C=a/c=100/500=1/5.$$
Hence
$$A/C=1/5\Leftrightarrow C=5A \Rightarrow 375=A+C=A+5A=6A \Rightarrow A=375/6=62.5$$
Finally $C=5A=375\cdot 5/6=312.5$.

Comment: Thank you Robert for prompt reply but this is maybe to high level to complete for me. I don't seem to get it .

Comment: thank you this is what I searched for

Comment: Thank you Robert, I will for sure, 

But what do I do if I got other variable that does not change?


the same principle but if 

 a=100; b=225; c=400; d= 100;  and E is the sum of all that comes to 825

and I resize the 825 to 600 and  I leave b as it is , how do I than do the formula, because you done against each other of A/C

Comment: I also could not understand how you or where you got " A+5A=375". Why is it A+ 5A

Comment: @ChrisGuru Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, perfect,know I got it.

Answer (score 0):

- $$\text{a}+\text{b}+\text{c}=\text{D}\to100+225+500=825$$

So:

$$\text{a}+225+\text{c}=600\Longleftrightarrow\text{a}+\text{c}=600-225=375$$

Now, use:

$$\frac{\text{a}}{\text{c}}=\frac{100}{500}=\frac{1}{5}$$

So, solve the system:

$$\frac{\text{a}}{\text{c}}=\frac{1}{5},\text{a}+\text{c}=375$$

For $\text{a}$ we find $62.5$ and for $\text{b}$ we find $312.5$

Comment: I am trying to figure out how would you write this in calculator (formula)?

Comment: Use wolframalpha and give as input: a/c=1/5,a+c=375